# Highlight the first button in a UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uialertview

I am developing an iPad application. I have an alert box with two buttons, "YES" and "NO".

```
alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirmation!" 
                                 message:@"Would you like to continue placing the order ?" 
                                delegate:self 
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"YES" 
                       otherButtonTitles:@"NO", nil];
alert.tag=100;
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

In the alert box, the "YES" button is dark and "NO" is highlighted, but I want the reverse. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just switch the YES and the NO. Or do you want to keep their positions?

Comment: But I have used it about 30 places and have added functionality on YES/NO buttons so I will need to change all the functionality

Answer (score 1):

Switch your 'YES' and 'NO'. Though you have used in in many places and added functionality, I don't think it will be of much trouble ... In this method : didDismissWithButtonIndex, just switch the index, i.e, if you wrote the functionality of 'YES' in button index 1, change it to 0 in the if condition : `if(buttonIndex==0)    { //Do job for NO }`
`else {//Do job for YES}`
Enjoy !! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you add cancel button it shows in dark and other button in light color. So if you want NO button in dark declare it as cancel button. You can refer the tutorial for this

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uialertview/

Comment: Is there any other way. instead of doing this

Comment: I didn't found any other way to do this